# Changing file permissions with root, will they remain if I unroot?

Tags: file-permissions

I currently use the run-as command through adb to be able to access the data folder of an app that I am developing directly on my phone using AIDE.

When connecting to the phone locally, using connectbot, I can find the run-as command in `/system/bin/` but it has no executable permission. There are other programs/scripts in that folder that do have executable permissions and I can run them.

My question is this. If I root my phone, I can change the executable permissions of run-as. If I then remove the root, will these permissions remain?

I'm not totally averse to rooting my phone permanently but if I don't need to, I'd rather not.

This is on a Galaxy Nexus.

---

I'm aware if I leave run-as executable then I'm possibly allowing myself wide open for security risks. But I am willing to risk it, even just to see if its possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

There's nothing magical to restore `/system` partition to original state. Many users gain root access temporarily to remove bloatwares from `/system/apps` & then unroot.

But, remember, if un-rooting method involves flashing `/system` image, you'll lose your changes. So, use proper un-rooting method.

Comment: Cheers Sachin.

Any ideas where I can get this 'proper' un-rooting method. Googling doesn't really filter on the word 'proper'

Comment: @RussWheeler By proper method, I mean remove `su` binary, SuperUser.apk etc & seal off any exploits. For one-click rooting & unrooting Galaxy Nexus, I have found only one software viz. [Wug's Nexus Root Toolkit](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-nexus-rooting-roms-hacks/147177-automated-wugs-nexus-root-toolkit-v1-5-3-updated-08-18-12-a.html) and looks like you are out of luck. It unroots by flashing whole original firmware. Its not proper way.

Comment: @RussWheeler Try to root temporarily: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1331258

Comment: @RussWheeler This one also looks promising: http://androidforums.com/verizon-galaxy-nexus-all-things-root/499117-galaxy-nexus-root-un-root-without-unlocking-bootloader.html

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I'll check them out later and let you know how I get on.

I'm very keen not to wipe any data though. If that's the case, I'd rather not root and keep plugging my phone in to get the db off it :)

Comment: @RussWheeler Your data will not be affected in any case..